# form validation with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, validation, submit

I have the following in my .net mvc razor form and I'm clicking on the submit button, but it's not being validated by the validation in the js. I debugged it in Firefox and instead, goes right to the form method and no validation comes out on the form to stop the form submission.

the HTML output of the model.LoanId is simply LoanId.

How can I properly validate the form????

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Refresh", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmTemps" })) 
    <tr>
                    <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoanId)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoanId)
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnRefresh" value='Refresh' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

js

$("#frmTemps").validate({
        event: "submit",
        rules: {
            LoanID: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            LoanID: {
                required: ' Please enter a Loan ID. '
            }
        }
    });

I also tried it with non-model data below and got the same thing.

    @Html.Label("loanid:", "LoanID")
                    @Html.TextBox("loanID")


Here is the html I'm trying to validate:
<td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoanType)
                    @Html.TextBox("SBA", "SBA")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoanType)
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoanType)*@
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="ddlDept">Department:</label>
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDeptText)
                            .Name("ddlDept")
                            .DataTextField("DepartmentName")
                            .DataValueField("DepartmentID")
                            .Events(e => e.Change("Refresh"))
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetDepartments", "Home");
                                });
                            })
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedDeptText)
```

**View Model**

```
public class ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors
{
    public int SelectedTemplateId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PDFTemplate> Templates { get; set; }

    public int SelectedGuarantorId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tGuarantor> Guarantors { get; set; }

    public string LoanId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDeptText { get; set; }
    public string LoanType { get; set; }

    public bool ShowTemps { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string ErrorT { get; set; }
    public string ErrorG { get; set; }
    public bool ShowGeneratePDFBtn { get; set; }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

**Validation class**

```
namespace PDFService03Validation.Validations
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(PDFService03_Validation))]
    public partial class PDFService03
    {

}

    public partial class PDFService03_Validation
    {
        public class PDFService03
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Loan ID Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string LoanID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Loan Type Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string LoanType { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Name Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string SelectedDeptText { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index method**

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors model)
{
    ViewBag.Error = "";

    model.ShowGeneratePDFBtn = false;

    return View();
}
```

`Index.cshtml` - still thinks the object is not set. When debugging, I go into my Controller, sets the variable in the model, then, comes back here. Please help... I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly here. I think I've followed everything as needed.

Sorry to bug you again, but I'm almost there....

I did as you said, but still am not getting any validation errors....

Below, is the html markup that is produced by my View. You can see the scripts I'm using at the top and you can also see the validation in the span tags. What am I missing??? 
I'm also going to show you the ViewModel I edited. thanks so much ahead of time...

ViewModel

```
namespace PDFConverterModel.ViewModels
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors_Validation))]
    public partial class ViewModelTemplate_GuarantorsValidation
    {

    }

    public partial class ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors_Validation
    {
        public class ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Loan ID Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string LoanID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Loan Type Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string LoanType { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Name Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string SelectedDeptText { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors
    {
        public int SelectedTemplateId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PDFTemplate> Templates { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGuarantorId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tGuarantor> Guarantors { get; set; }

        public string LoanId { get; set; }
        public string SelectedDeptText { get; set; }
        public string LoanType { get; set; }

        public bool ShowTemps { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public string ErrorT { get; set; }
        public string ErrorG { get; set; }
        public bool ShowGeneratePDFBtn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Page output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BHG :: PDF Generator</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>BHG :: PDF Generator</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">


<h2></h2>

<div>

    <table style="width: 1000px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img alt="BHG Logo" src="/Images/logo.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>

<form action="/Home/Refresh" id="frmTemps" method="post">            <tr>
                <td>


                <label for="LoanId">LoanId</label>
                <input id="LoanId" name="LoanId" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LoanId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnRefresh" value='Refresh' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="LoanType">LoanType</label>
                    <input id="SBA" name="SBA" type="text" value="SBA" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LoanType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="ddlDept">Department:</label>
                    <input id="ddlDept" name="ddlDept" type="text" /><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#ddlDept").kendoDropDownList({"change":Refresh,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Home/GetDepartments"}},"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"dataTextField":"DepartmentName","dataValueField":"DepartmentID"});});
</script>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SelectedDeptText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
</form>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('btnRefresh').on('click', '#btnRefresh', function () {
        Refresh();
    });

    function Refresh() {

        var LoanID = $("#LoanID").val();

        if (LoanID != "") {
            document.forms["frmTemps"].submit();
        }
    }
</script>

        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh... I see why this is happening. You're forgetting this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoanId)
```

If you don't put the `ValidationMessageFor`, the unobtrusive validation won't know that this model property needs to be validated before the form submission.

So you must have this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoanId)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoanId)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoanId)
```

Don't forget to put some data annotation in your `LoanId` property first...

For more on this, look here: [Validation with the Data Annotation Validators (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

**EDIT**

After you provided more code to the question I could see why the validation errors are not showing.

This happens because you're actually passing your custom ViewModel `ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors` to the view. As you can see, your view model has no data annotations. The data annotations you provided in the metadata class `PDFService03_Validation` will only take effect if you pass an object of type `PDFService03` to the view. So to solve the problem you'll have to duplicate your data annotations in your `ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors` view model object. This is code repetition and is terrible ugly but is how it works.

Comment: What you said I know is correct, but the validation doesn't kick in on the page or in the model.

Comment: You don't need that `validate` JavaScript code in your view to validate the fields. If you add the required JavaScript files namely: `jquery-1.#.#`, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` they should take care of wiring up the validation using the data annotations you provided in your model. Those JavaScript files can be found in the Scripts folder of your ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but am still getting the same error. I'm going to modify my question so you can see the code and hopefully point out what is wrong....

Comment: You tried to edit my answer... you should edit your question. :)

Comment: sounds stupid, but i don't see a link to edit my question after someone gives a response.... If you could let me know, thanks...

Comment: Really? There's an edit button right beside the share button bellow your question. Let me know if you can see it...

Comment: Yes, I placed edits here a lot. The thing is, is that you can't format any code in there and has a limit of characters..... So, where am I supposed to put updated (of code) to my original request.

Comment: I edited your question with the content you posted while trying to edit my answer. I also updated my answer. Check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

1. jquery-1.7.1.min.j
2. kendo.web.min.js
3. kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js
4. kendo.validator.min.js
5. kendo.dataviz.min.js

These 5 files are necessary for the validation to work. I have seen you have added few of these add all these and try. I also faced this problem but this have solved the problem.

also check you web config for this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

This is also required. Let me no f it works.